# python logging Father Child hierarchy

Tags: python, logging, hierarchy

I am trying to create a Father/Child logging hierarchy by first creating a Father.Child log and then re-call Father log using logging.getLogger() but for some reason I cannot get it to work properly.
below is code example. in the real project there will be lots of classes which will create a self.logger using 'clsLogger' and each class will write the logs to the same log file for all classes.

```
import logging
class clsLogger():

def __init__(self,LoggerName,Child=False,LoggerFileName='QpythonLog.txt'):
    #create logger :
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(LoggerName)
    self.lvl = logging.DEBUG
    self.logger.setLevel(self.lvl)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  %(name)s  %(filename)s  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

    #log to file :
    self.filehandler = logging.FileHandler(LoggerFileName)
    self.filehandler.setLevel = self.lvl
    self.logger.addHandler(self.filehandler)
    self.filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    #log to console :
    self.consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    self.consoleHandler.setLevel(self.lvl)
    self.logger.addHandler(self.consoleHandler)
    self.consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)


log1 = clsLogger('Father.Child')
log1 = clsLogger('Father')
log1.logger.info('log from father')
log1 = clsLogger('Father.Child')
log1.logger.info('log from child')
```

The output (which is wrong) is :

```
2020-06-26 00:36:11,727  Father  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from father
2020-06-26 00:36:11,819  Father.Child  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from child
2020-06-26 00:36:11,819  Father.Child  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from child
2020-06-26 00:36:11,819  Father.Child  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from child
```

Which I really want it to be :

```
2020-06-26 00:36:11,727  Father  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from father
2020-06-26 00:36:11,819  Father.Child  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from child
```

It looks like every time I use logger.getLogger it creates a new logger object, instead of using the first created Father.Child hierarchy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It looks like every time I use logger.getLogger it creates a new logger object, instead of using the first created Father.Child hierarchy

Certainly not. The logging module registers each logger in an internal dictionary (`logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict`) with its name. By definition, there can be only one logger per given name. As per the `logging` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects):

> Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

You can verify this in your code as follows:

```
<your code here>

# This is accessing an undocumented member; not safe for production code
print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)

# Output:
# {'Father.Child': <Logger Father.Child (DEBUG)>, 'Father': <Logger Father (DEBUG)>}
```

The issue is that every time you instantiate your `clsLogger` class you create identical handlers and attach them to a logger that might already be existing.

---

Breaking it down, this:

```
log1 = clsLogger('Father.Child')
```

creates a logger named `Father.Child` and attaches one `FileHandler` and one `StreamHandler` to it. Then this:

```
log1 = clsLogger('Father')
```

creates a logger named `Father`, that becomes the parent of `Father.Child`as per the name and attaches identical handlers to it.
The next line:

```
log1.logger.info('log from father')
```

sends a message to the `Father` logger, that emits it to its two handlers, hence the line:

```
2020-06-26 00:36:11,727  Father  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from father
```

on the console and in the file. This line:

```
log1 = clsLogger('Father.Child')
```

fetches the *existing* logger named `Father.Child` and attaches another `FileHandler` and `StreamHandler` to it. So your last line:

```
log1.logger.info('log from child')
```

sends the message to each of the two `StreamHandler` and `FileHandler` instances of the `Father.Child` logger, plus, since `Father` is the parent of `Father.Child` and you do not explicitly disable [propagation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate), also sends the log record to `Father` which emits it to its own `StreamHandler` and `FileHandler`. That's why you get the output three times.

This can be made visible like this:

```
<your code here>

for lname, logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items():
    print(lname, logger.handlers, logger.parent)

# Output
# Father.Child [<FileHandler /home/shmee/.PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/QpythonLog.txt (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (DEBUG)>, <FileHandler /home/shmee/.PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/QpythonLog.txt (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (DEBUG)>] <Logger Father (DEBUG)>
# Father [<FileHandler /home/shmee/.PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/QpythonLog.txt (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (DEBUG)>] <RootLogger root (WARNING)>
```

As an aside: you are setting the level for the `FileHandler` incorrectly:

```
self.filehandler.setLevel = self.lvl
```

hence the level `NOTSET` for these handlers. You're doing it correctly for the `StreamHandler`:

```
self.consoleHandler.setLevel(self.lvl)
```

To achieve what you want, you would basically do:

```
class clsLogger():

def __init__(self,LoggerName,Child=False,LoggerFileName='QpythonLog.txt'):
    #create logger :
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(LoggerName)
    self.lvl = logging.DEBUG
    self.logger.setLevel(self.lvl)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  %(name)s  %(filename)s  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

    #log to file :
    self.filehandler = logging.FileHandler(LoggerFileName)
    self.filehandler.setLevel(self.lvl)
    self.logger.addHandler(self.filehandler)
    self.filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    #log to console :
    self.consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    self.consoleHandler.setLevel(self.lvl)
    self.logger.addHandler(self.consoleHandler)
    self.consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    self.logger.propagate = not Child


clsLogger('Father.Child', True)
clsLogger('Father')
logging.getLogger('Father').info('log from father')
logging.getLogger('Father.Child').info('log from child')

# Output
# 2020-06-26 00:36:11,727  Father  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from father
# 2020-06-26 00:36:11,819  Father.Child  Services_TalynM_TalynA_v2.py  INFO: log from child
```

**However**, your class is pretty much boilerplate code. As the docs state (emphasis mine):

> **Note**: If you attach a handler to a logger and one or more of its ancestors, it may emit the same record multiple times. **In general, you should not need to attach a handler to more than one logger** - if you just attach it to the appropriate logger which is highest in the logger hierarchy, then it will see all events logged by all descendant loggers, provided that their propagate setting is left set to True. **A common scenario is to attach handlers only to the root logger, and to let propagation take care of the rest.**

So, using the implicit root logger, the following would achieve the exact same thing, but give you more flexibility with additional loggers in, or next to, your hierarchy:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
handlers = [logging.FileHandler('QpythonLog.txt'), logging.StreamHandler()]
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  %(name)s  %(filename)s  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
[h.setFormatter(formatter) for h in handlers]
[logger.addHandler(h) for h in handlers]
[e.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) for e in (logger, *handlers)]

logging.getLogger('Father').info('log from father')
logging.getLogger('Father.Child').info('log from child')
logging.getLogger('Father.Child.GrandChild').info('log from grandchild')
logging.getLogger('sthElse').info('log from something else')

# Output
# 2020-06-26 01:45:37,617  Father  frek.py  INFO: log from father
# 2020-06-26 01:45:37,617  Father.Child  frek.py  INFO: log from child
# 2020-06-26 01:45:37,617  Father.Child.GrandChild  frek.py  INFO: log from grandchild
# 2020-06-26 01:45:37,617  sthElse  frek.py  INFO: log from something else
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
log1 = clsLogger('Father.Child') # <-- creates logger, attached 2 handlers
log1 = clsLogger('Father') # <-- creates logger, attaches 2 handlers
# ^^ WILL ALSO HANDLE logs sent to Father.Child
log1.logger.info('log from father')
log1 = clsLogger('Father.Child') # <-- retrieves first logger, ADDS 2 NEW HANDLERS!
log1.logger.info('log from child')
```

So, don't call your fn twice for the same log name, or you add another pair of handlers and therefore create multiple outputs.

If you don't want logs sent to Child to percolate upwards to Father (and then to root), then set `Child.propagate = False`.

Additionally, you're opening the same file three times; this is likely to cause problems with overwriting or interleaved output.